# Is there a minimal set of DNS records that serves as a standard for all websites?

Tags: dns

Is there a minimal set of DNS records that serves as a standard for all websites to adhere to? Was there any attempt to create such a standard by an international Internet authority?

<sub>By the way, this question is quite a follow up for [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499757/understanding-sendmail-binary).</sub>

Comment: Why do you need a standard for that? A website is like any other host on Internet. To be reachable it needs its name to resolve to one or more IPv4 and/or IPv6 addresses, which is achieved in the DNS through `A`+`AAAA` records, optionnally through `CNAME` records. In theory `SRV` records would have fit the bill too and be more powerful/generic but browser makers have clearly stated they won't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a standard as such. Personally I always `A` and `AAAA` records to resolve sites and I avoid `CName`s as it's another DNS lookup.

I recommend `DNSsec` as well for that bit of added protection and proper mail server records including `MX`, `SPF`, `DKIM`, `DMARC` as strict as possible to stop your domain being flagged.

Comment: Hi, please see suggested edit. Also, please add a few words on if for you, AAAA is replacing CName. BTW, I misunderstand what you meant about CName being another DNS lookup. Thank you for the answer and also if you take care of this.